# Need help understanding foreign keys

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a message class with a foreign key that should be the id of the author who wrote the message. As I understand it, the foreign key in the message class should look like the class below.

Setting the foreign key as the author object as below, seems absurd because instead of a short and human readable id like "5", I get a *very* long string in the database that isn't human readable.

I'm missing something, right?

message class:

```
public class Message {
...
private Author author; // this is the foreign key

...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME")
public User getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(Author author) {
    this.author = author;
}
...
```

Creating the message object to be saved:

```
Author author = ...
message.setAuthor(author);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are simply looking for a Many-to-One unidirectional relationship

```
@Entity
public class Message {
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="USERNAME")
private Author author;

@Entity
public class Author {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="USERNAME")
private Long USERNAME;
```

Comment: For this to work, I need to set the author as message.setAuthor(author), right? This means that the database entry for the message doesn't just contain the authors id or username, but the entire author object. Right? It *seems* very wasteful and complicated, because the content of the object isn't human readable, unlike the authors username.

Comment: @CaptainHindsight: no. Not at all. Read Hibernate's documentation about associations. Hibernate maps this association between objects using a join column (hence the `@JoinColumn` annotation), which contains the ID of the author associated to the message.

Comment: Right, in that case I'm doing something wrong because right now my database contains a whole lot of gibberish. I'll read on, thanks.

Comment: as already said you don't need the whole author object, see a complete example with table definition: http://simone-folino.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/jpa-onetomany-and-manytoone_27.html

Comment: so basically your message table has a field called username which will be the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You do not post the annotations from the Author class. And it is highly probable that You are missing annotations on the Author class site. Nevertheless look below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bill")
public class BillModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "bill_id")
    private Integer billId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_shop_id")
    private Shop shop;

// getters and setters
```

}

and class Shop

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop")
public class Shop {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "shop_id")
    private Integer shopId;

    @Column(name = "shop_name")
    private String shopName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<BillModel> billModels = new HashSet<BillModel>();

// getters and setters
}
```